# Have I properly commented this piece of my query?

Tags: sql-server

I feel like this deserves a good comment but I get the feeling that what I have is merely a distraction.

1. Does this deserve a comment?
2. If so, can this comment be improved?

*Please note that I am working with a poorly normalized application.*

```
(   
    /* Remove Time Portion From ActivityDate */  
    DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, Activity.ActivityDate), 0) Not Between        
    /* Remove Time Portion From @MinimumDate Or SQL Server Min DateTime */   
    DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, Coalesce(@MinimumDate, '1753-01-01')), 0) And
    /* Remove Time Portion From @MaximumDate Or SQL Server Max DateTime */  
    DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, Coalesce(@MaximumDate, '9999-12-31')), 0) 
)
```

Comment: You'd probably be best (if this is in a WHERE clause) reworking this such that the @MinimumDate becomes 'midnight on that date' and the @MaximumDate becomes 'midnight on the day after' and then do Activity.ActivityDate < @MinimumDate OR Activity.ActivityDate >= @MaximumDate - if you've an index on ActivityDate then this'd give the query optimizer a fighting chance.

Comment: @Will - Now that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap the dateadd/datediff in a scalar udf with a self commenting name and then pass in `Activity.ActivityDate` or `Coalesce(@MinimumDate, '1753-01-01'))` as parameters

So you'd have this:

```
(   
    dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (Activity.ActivityDate) NOT BETWEEN        
         dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (COALESCE(@MinimumDate, '1753-01-01')) AND
         dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (COALESCE(@MaximumDate, '9999-12-31')) 
)
```

You could also have a "date if null" parameter and deal with COALESCE in the udf if it's common enough in the SQL code

```
(   
    dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (Activity.ActivityDate, DEFAULT) NOT BETWEEN        
         dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (@MinimumDate, '1753-01-01') AND
         dbo.ufnGetDateOnly (@MaximumDate, '9999-12-31') 
)
```

Now it's obvious...no?

Comment: Something like this would have been immediately obvious were I dealing with your typical language. One thing to consider though is the rather large performance hit when dealing with large result sets.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: A one line scalar udf is neither here nor there really, even for large resultsets. In this case, only Activity.ActivityDate would be parsed per row hopefully. I'd tend to calculare the min/max before the query and use local variables...

Comment: OK, how do I explain the seemingly magical null replacement values. It would be nice if SQL Server had some kind of function I could use. Something similar to `MaxValue(DateTime)`. Then again I could wrap that into a function as well.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Indeed... where do you strike the balance? You could also have functions such as dbo.ufnGetMinimumDateOnly too if you have to repeat coalesce all over...

Comment: This is the way to go. Quite frankly I hate comments.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think you don't need comments that say `removes X from Y` or `increments X by Y` etc...

That being said, if you feel like you need to comment a particular section of code, I'd try to focus on the intent and big picture of the functionality.  For instance, why were things implemented this way?  That way, the next guy that comes along behind you will have a fighting chance when he has to make changes.

For instance, I know what your snippet of code does functionally, but I have no idea why it is there or how it relates to the rest of the application.  A possible improvement could be something along the lines of an explanation of the functionality that you would give someone new to the code, or someone who might not care **how** it's implemented, but **why**.

I always have to remind myself that **programming is communicating** and the more clearly you can communicate your intent to other programmers, the better off you'll be.  If you can find a way to add comments that improves the quality of communication between developers, then go for it.  I'd argue that comments that tell you exactly what the code is doing is counterproductive and hurts communication in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are helpful to me, because I would have had to think about what those lines are doing if they were not there. Although as Robert Greiner says, why you are doing this would also be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do ***not*** document what you do. It must be self explanatory what a single line of code does. Document:

- What is the primary role, implemented logic of a block? (e.g. a function, a loop)
- Constraints, assumptions (null value?, thread safe? read-only?)
- Why is it like this and not elsehow?  (e.g. Architectural decisions, we are going to use this XML parses because we need namespace support and because that other one does not support EBDIC encoding)
- Where is this in the big picture? Where is it called from?
- Schema (including DB constraints, assumptions, e.g. escaped?)
- Implications (e.g. security considerations, side effects)
- Dependencies (e.g. libraries, headers, a magic lock file on a floppy disk)